# Creating an installer package file like .MSI for Linux using Chef

Tags: chef

We are building an analytic application. As a part of final deployment we are planning to install the application using an installer tool.Need to create an  installer package like MSI for installing the application using Chef.I hardly find time to learn about the Chef.It would be better if there are any link that can guide me through the process of building an installer package file like MSI.

Comment: create a proper package or set of packages for your target distribution(s).

Comment: I happened to read about Habitat which can be used for packaging the solution.Will it suffice my above requirement.

Comment: Only you can decide that. As an admin, I would much rather install a .deb or .rpm file and let my distribution take care of dependencies...

Comment: Point is I am new to Linux environment, i need to know whether we can create a .rpm package that will interact with the user using Chef. Based on the user input, configuration is done on the run time.

Comment: Read this question and accepted answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34631942/how-to-run-and-interact-with-a-script-from-within-an-rpm

Comment: This is not the exact thing which i was looking into. I happen to read about Omnibus. I think that would suffice my requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chef is a configuration management tool. It does not build packages. Perhaps you are thinking of Omnibus? That’s made my the Chef dev team but is distinct as a project.

Comment: Yes Omnibus is something would suffice my requirement.But any links to get it done combining Chef cookbook with Omnibus

Comment: Chef is not involved in that, you just run Omnibus yourself and it makes a package. Chef might install it on your server(s), but it has nothing to do with building packages.

Comment: I am creating a package for java  based web application,that has dependency with other technology.Say for example to deploy java application we need web server like Tomcat.In my case the package should interact with user to decide from where to install tomcat.Say some user  allow the tomcat installation using yum  or follow the default installation method.In default installation method, we have the tar file.In chef cookbook we can mention the tar file location.Also in omnibus I am not sure where to mention the location.That is the reason I choose chef cookbook with Omnibus

Comment: Those two things are unrelated. Either you include Tomcat in your Omnibus package and the user gets no choice, or you don't and your package doesn't know anything about Tomcat.

Comment: Correct. Using omnibus we are building the installer. Also there is no interaction with the user.